# How the bandwidth distance product rule is applied?

Tags: bandwidth

I read the following in one reference:
A copper wire (twisted pair), the link traditionally associated with low bit rate transmission, is still in use in the modern data centers transmitting data at 20 Gbit/sec. The secret? it does so only over a few meters (the bandwidth distance product is constant).
My question:  I know that optical fibers, for example, are used for high data rate transmission over long distances. High data rates means high bandwidth and high carrier frequency. According to the constant bandwidth distance constant principle, we can decrease the carrier frequencies used with optical fibers, and thus increase the transmission distance. My question is: can we use very low frequencies (in the range of kilohertz) with optical fibers to transmit data over very large distances? Of course the bit rate will be very low, but I am asking about the possibility to transmit very low frequencies over optical fibers.

Comment: This might be a better fit for the physics stackexchange. Having said that, my understanding is that the nice properties of an optical fiber occur at frequencies in a specific range, a few hundreds of nm. Just like a mirror does not reflect RF nor X-rays -- a material's properties are frequency selective.

Comment: BTW, consider updating the title of your question, which is completely unrelated to the actual question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. You gain nothing by changing the carrier frequency in a Fiber Optic.

Without any concrete data, we cannot precisely answer this.

But let's say we have a 20GHz Badwidth signal.

For a copper wire, the distributed cable impedance will impose a significative atenuation, hence you signal will be lost at a few meters.

Instead, for a Fiber Optic cable, the attenuation at this bandwidth will be enough to surpass copper as you know.

Carrier Frequency is out of the Bandwidth Distance product empiric relation. Has no place in here. Copper wire do not use a carrier frequency. Fiber Optic do use the laser carrier frequency.

Remember also, that a kHz frequency electromagnetic signal is in the radiofrequency spectrum, not in the optical spectrum. Intending to pass a kHz radiofrequency signal through a Fiber Optic will simply consume the signal faster than through copper.